# Unable to append html element to the parent in Vue js directive

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a global directive in vue js

```
Vue.directive('customDirective',{
    bind(el,binding,vnode){
        // need to get the parent
        // append a div after the input element
    }
})
```

I have the following html code .

```
<div class="parentDiv">
<input type="text" name="firstName" v-customDirective="Some text"/>
</div>
```

`<div class="parentDiv"> is loading dynamically via jquery`. I need to get the parent of input tag and need to append some html after the input tag. I have tried with parent(), but it is showing as **parent is not a function**. Any suggestions ?

Comment: When is `parentDiv` being added to the DOM? After the Vue is created?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the `inserted` hook instead of `bind` if you want to access the parent element.

You can get the parent element via `el.parentElement`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use vnode, and Vue nextTick.

```
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.directive('customDirective',{
    bind(el,binding,vnode){
        Vue.bextTick(() => {
            let parent = vnode.elm.parentElement;
        });
    }
})
```

If you want to use parent() which is the jQuery function, you must get the element by jQuery.

```
Vue.directive('customDirective',{
    bind(el,binding,vnode){
        Vue.bextTick(() => {
            let id = vnode.elm.id;
            let parent = jQuery('#'+id).parent();
        });
    }
})
```

I'm not sure, that second code works, but it will be something like that.